# How do I make a boat jump?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

Me and a friend are trying to make a ice boat racing map and wanted to recreate our favorite mario kart map as a boat racing map however said map has a lot of jumps. I want a way i can make a boat jump through the air while moving foward. So far i have found that riding a boat through a bubble column gives it a small 1 block jump but it requires extremely precise timing and is a pain to use. Does anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: If anyone cares the map we are trying to recreate is mario kart 8 excitebike arena.

Comment: People have done stuff with slime blocks and pressure plates. Maybe worth experimenting with. Or a player permanently standing ready with a fishing rod. ;)

Comment: Fabian Röling thx for the suggestion

Answer (score 3):

Using pistons, slime blocks, and pressure plates you could make it so as you hit the pressure plate, it activates a piston, and launches you about 10-12 blocks upward. If you want it more controlled and more consistent, you could add a timer use a piston to hit the boat with a slime block and launch it forward towards the end of the jump. Don't place the pressure plates on the piston, as it will destroy the pressure plate and make it a one time use.